# OctoberCMS, how to sort order of the records data set (json structure) by option from previous page?

Tags: jquery, json, sorting, twig, octobercms

Is anyone know how to sort order of this records data set by value from previous page?

**Eg.**

**1st Page (Previous page)**: Dropdown select option value : 1,2,3

*when*

selected 1 : will make records sorting as default,

selected 2 : will make sorting by interest number,

selected 3 : will make sorting by name

**2nd Page (This page)**

{% for offer in offers %}

re-order as selected option

[2nd page's records data set (json structure)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRnQd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first its hard to sort `JSON` instead what we can do we can convert it to `array` and then we can sort it,

> and i also suggest to move this JSON code in `code section` of page.

so now in your page `code section`

```
// this method will execute at start of page
function onStart() {   

    // you can replace your json data here inside single quotation
    $offers = '[
        { "name" : "a"},
        { "name" : "c"},
        { "name" : "b"}
    ]';    

    // this is orders based on incoming param
    $sortingOrders = [
        // default (no sorting at all)
        1 => 'default', 
        // sort ascending on names
        2 => ['field' => 'name' , 'direction' => 'asc'], 
        // sort ascending on numbers
        3 => ['field' => 'number' , 'direction' => 'asc'],        
        // extra sort descending on names
        4 => ['field' => 'name' , 'direction' => 'desc'], 
    ];    

    // conver json data in-to array
    $arrayOffers = json_decode ($offers, true);    

    // taking paramert of sorting (you can use your own logic here)
    // $order will be 1 2 3 or 4 passed from previous page
    $order = $this->param('order');

    // we do some checks if given order exists
    if( $order && isset($sortingOrders[$order]) && is_array($sortingOrders[$order]) ) {

        // if order is exists we do sorting
        $this->sortBy($sortingOrders[$order]['field'], $arrayOffers, $sortingOrders[$order]['direction']);
    }

    // assign data to page
    $this['arrayOffers'] = $arrayOffers;
}

// helper function will sort the data
function sortBy($field, &$array, $direction = 'asc')
{
    // array is pass by refenence so it will modify it directly

    // sorting logic
    usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($field, $direction) {

        if(!isset($a[$field])) {
            return 0;
        }

        $a = $a[$field];
        $b = $b[$field];
        if ($a == $b) return 0;
        $direction = strtolower(trim($direction));
        if($direction == 'asc') {
            return $a < $b ? -1 : 1;
        }     
        return $a > $b ? -1 : 1;     
    });

    return true;
}
```

now inside your page `Markup section` just put this code which will just display data `sorted`, as `arrayOffers` is already sorted.

```
<ul>
    {% for offer in arrayOffers %}
        <li> {{offer.name}}</li>            
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

> Now you can use `/testing/:order?` as page slug

and then you can use this page as

`/testing` will `show default order`

`/testing/1` will `show default order`

`/testing/2` will show `sort asc on names`

Comment: "No you can use /testing/:order? as page slug" I guess you means "Now", right? Anyway i was try following your advice, the result run very well with slug. I will going next on passing value. Thank you so much.

Comment: yes sorry edited, thanks for pointing it out :) , you need to add your change here `$order = $this->param('order');` you can get value from `post` or `get` etc